# Div not wrapping around all items in a loop

Tags: php, html

I got 2 sections on a page.  You can see it here: http://www.equitasmg.com/who-we-are-2/

Both sections have a `<div>` wrapped around them, but the first section "Our Leadership" seems to not like the `<div>`.  The `<div>` wraps around the first item in the section but does not wrap around all the items.

Here is the PHP for both sections.

**First section**

```
 <center><h2>Our Leadership</h2></center>
 <center><div>
 <?php
 $people= get_field('people');
 $a=0;
 foreach ($people as $r) {
$a++;
?>
          <div class="people">
            <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team'];?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
            <h3>
                <?php echo $r['name'];?>
            </h3>
            <div class="position">
                <h4><?php echo $r['position'];?></h4>
            </div>
            <?php echo $r['intro_text'];?>
            <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
            <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>">Learn More</a>
            <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
 <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

<h3><?php echo $r['name'];?></h3>
<div class="position">
    <?php echo $r['position'];?>
</div>
<div class="content">       
<?php echo $r['learn_more_text'];?>
</div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
 </div>
        </div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div></center>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**Second section**

```
 <center><h2>Our Team</h2></center>
 <center><div>
 <?php
 $people2= get_field('people_bottomsection');
 $a=0;
 foreach ($people2 as $r) {
$a++;
?>
          <div class="people">
            <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team'];?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
            <h3>
                <?php echo $r['name'];?>
            </h3>
            <div class="position">
                <h4><?php echo $r['position'];?></h4>
            </div>
            <?php echo $r['intro_text'];?>
            <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
            <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>">Learn More</a>
            <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
 <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

<h3><?php echo $r['name'];?></h3>
<div class="position">
    <?php echo $r['position'];?>
</div>
<div class="content">       
<?php echo $r['learn_more_text'];?>
</div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
 </div>
        </div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div></center>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Css meaning for the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You just got extra div.

First section you got extra div here

```html
<center><h2>Our Leadership</h2></center>
<center>
<div>
<?php
$people= get_field('people');
$a=0;
foreach ($people as $r) {
$a++;
?>
<div class="people">
<img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team'];?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
<h3>
<?php echo $r['name'];?>
</h3>
<div class="position">
<h4><?php echo $r['position'];?></h4>
</div>
<?php echo $r['intro_text'];?>
<?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
<a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>">Learn More</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
<div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

 <h3><?php echo $r['name'];?></h3>
 <div class="position">
 <?php echo $r['position'];?>
 </div>
 <div class="content">       
 <?php echo $r['learn_more_text'];?>
 </div>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
<!-- </div> --> //extra div here
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?> //end of foreach
</div>
</center>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

second section

```html
<center><h2>Our Team</h2></center>
<center>
 <div>
 <?php
 $people2= get_field('people_bottomsection');
 $a=0;
 foreach ($people2 as $r) {
 $a++;
 ?>
  <div class="people">
   <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team'];?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:100%;">
   <h3>
   <?php echo $r['name'];?>
   </h3>
   <div class="position">
   <h4><?php echo $r['position'];?></h4>
   </div>
  <?php echo $r['intro_text'];?>
  <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
  <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>">Learn More</a>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
   <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

    <h3><?php echo $r['name'];?></h3>
    <div class="position">
    <?php echo $r['position'];?>
    </div>
    <div class="content">       
    <?php echo $r['learn_more_text'];?>
    </div>
   <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
   </div>
  <!-- </div> --> //extra div 
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
</center>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Now how do I get the div to control the items inside of it?  Is there a CSS property that allows a div to take control?  eg: center the contents within?

Comment: I can't use a fixed height or width to the div because it needs to be mobile responsive.

Comment: fixed it.  text-align:center on the parent div.  margin:auto and display:inline-block on the child divs.

Comment: Also added overflow: hidden to the parent div so that it would take control over the child divs.  other people may have to experiment with it if they have the same problem I am having.